# Can I refer to variables created earlier in a MySQL select statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a select statement that calculates the due date for tasks that needs to be completed regularly.  If a task has been completed before, it uses the date of that completion plus an interval.  If the task hasn't been completed before, the due date comes from a column which records the first time a task needs to be completed.  I then want to show all
The syntax needs using again in the where statement but as it's a little convoluted, I wanted to avoid repeating it verbatim.  I'd tried to use a variable, but the code doesn't work when I do so.  I'm new to SQL so any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I've written:

```
SELECT  t.task, 
    t.zone,
    @duedate:=if(date(if(t.date_completed is null, t.begin_date, 
        adddate(t.date_completed,s.due_in_x_days)))<current_date(),
        current_date(),
        date(if(t.date_completed is null,t.begin_date,adddate(t.date_completed,s.due_in_x_days))))
        as due_date
from tasks t
inner join schedules_v s
where t.schedule=s.timetable
and if(date(if(t.date_completed is null,t.begin_date,adddate(t.date_completed,s.due_in_x_days)))<current_date(),
        current_date(),
        date(if(t.date_completed is null,t.begin_date,adddate(t.date_completed,s.due_in_x_days))))
            between curdate() and last_day(curdate())
order by 2,1;
```

I'd hoped to change the line:

```
    and if(date(if(t.date_completed is null,t.begin_date,adddate(t.date_completed,s.due_in_x_days)))<current_date(),
        current_date(),
        date(if(t.date_completed is null,t.begin_date,adddate(t.date_completed,s.due_in_x_days))))
            between curdate() and last_day(curdate())
```

to this:

```
    and @due_date between curdate() and last_day(curdate())
```

That gives me no returns, however.  Is it possible to use a variable in this way? Thanks for any help!

Comment: User-defined variable is available from the definition (by assigning a value) till connection close, its value cannot change without a code which change it explicitly. The variable which was not defined is accessible too - but its value is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the where clause is executed before the select fields, you would have to do it the other way around, doing:

```
SELECT  t.task, 
    t.zone,
    @duedate as due_date
from tasks t
inner join schedules_v s
where t.schedule=s.timetable
and (@duedate:=if(date(if(t.date_completed is null,t.begin_date,adddate(t.date_completed,s.due_in_x_days)))<current_date(),
        current_date(),
        date(if(t.date_completed is null,t.begin_date,adddate(t.date_completed,s.due_in_x_days)))))
            between curdate() and last_day(curdate())
order by 2,1;
```

(Note that you mentioned both @duedate and @due_date.)